# The difference between \pgfkeysvalueof and /.store in

Tags: pgfkeys

I thought using `\pgfkeysvalueof` on a key that does not have a `/.store in` and the variable of a key that does have a `/.store in` would give the same result. This seems not to be the case.

This example, using `/.store in` for the key `overlay` works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{overpic}

\pgfkeys{
    /icon/.cd,
    width/.initial,
    overlay/.initial,
    overlay/.store in=\iconoverlay,
    set defaults/.unknown/.code={\pgfkeys{/icon/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.default=#1}}
}
\newcommand\icondefaults[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/icon/set defaults/.cd, #1}%
}
\newcommand\ifkeyempty[3]{%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{\keyvalue}%
    \ifempty{\keyvalue}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand\ifempty[3]{%
    \def\novalue{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
    \def\empty{}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefequal{#1}{\empty}} or test {\ifdefequal{#1}{\novalue}}}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\icon}[2][]{%
    {%
        \pgfkeys{/icon/.cd,width,overlay,#1}% Reset to default values
        \def\options{}%
        \ifkeyempty{/icon/width}{}{\edef\options{width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/icon/width},\options}}%
        \ifempty{\iconoverlay}{%
            \edef\graphic{\noexpand\includegraphics[\options]{#2}}%
        }{%
            \edef\overlay{\noexpand\begin{overpic}[\options]{#2}}%
            \def\graphic{\overlay\put(0,0){\iconoverlay}\end{overpic}}%
        }%
        \graphic%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\icondefaults{width=6cm}
\icon{example-image} % Image gets default width 6cm
\icon[width=2cm,overlay={\icon{example-image-overlay}}]{example-image} % Image gets width 2cm, while the overlaid image gets default width 6cm
\icon{example-image} % Image gets default width 6cm

\end{document}
```

While this example does not work. The only difference is that `/.store in` is not used for the key `overlay`, and hence `\pgfkeysvalueof` is used to access the value of the key. It results in an error `TeX capacity exceeded`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{overpic}

\pgfkeys{
    /icon/.cd,
    width/.initial,
    overlay/.initial,
    set defaults/.unknown/.code={\pgfkeys{/icon/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.default=#1}}
}
\newcommand\icondefaults[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/icon/set defaults/.cd, #1}%
}
\newcommand\ifkeyempty[3]{%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{\keyvalue}%
    \ifempty{\keyvalue}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand\ifempty[3]{%
    \def\novalue{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
    \def\empty{}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefequal{#1}{\empty}} or test {\ifdefequal{#1}{\novalue}}}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\icon}[2][]{%
    {%
        \pgfkeys{/icon/.cd,width,overlay,#1}% Reset to default values
        \def\options{}%
        \ifkeyempty{/icon/width}{}{\edef\options{width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/icon/width},\options}}%
        \ifkeyempty{/icon/overlay}{%
            \edef\graphic{\noexpand\includegraphics[\options]{#2}}%
        }{%
            \edef\overlay{\noexpand\begin{overpic}[\options]{#2}}%
            \def\graphic{\overlay\put(0,0){\pgfkeysvalueof{/icon/overlay}}\end{overpic}}%
        }%
        \graphic%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\icondefaults{width=6cm}
\icon{example-image} % Image gets default width 6cm
\icon[width=2cm,overlay={\icon{example-image-overlay}}]{example-image} % Image gets width 2cm, while the overlaid image gets default width 6cm
\icon{example-image} % Image gets default width 6cm

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know what is the difference between accessing a key's value through `\pgfkeysvalueof` and through it's `/.store in` variable?

Comment: Sorry for asking a question that has already been answered. The difference between \pgfkeysvaule of and /.store in has been thoroughly explained, but I was unable to find any explanation to why one of my examples works while not the other. I've posed a new question on this here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165300/using-key-value-interface-for-pgfkeys-results-in-error